# illegal else with no matching if

Tags: c++

It seems that my if statements are not working and I'm getting the "illegal else without matching if" error message. any help would be great, thanks.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int igame = 0;

int main()
{
    Sleep(1000);
    cout << "welcome to the Wild Casino!";
    Sleep(1000);
    cout << "\nplease select a game to play. 1 for Slots, 2 for Roulette, and 3 for Blackjack: ";
    cin >> igame;

    if (igame == 1);
    {
        cout << "\nWelcome to Slots";

    }
    else if (igame == 2);
    {
        cout << "\nWelcome to Roulette";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nWelcome to Blackjack";
    }


Sleep(1000000);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: `if (igame == 1);`, `else if (igame == 2);` Remove the semicolons `;`.

Comment: check your semicolons

Comment: thanks for the answers everyone it works great now!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (igame == 1);
```

You have an extra semicolon at the end - this is equivalent to

```
if (igame == 1) { }
```

Your code creates an ill-formed program:

```
if (igame == 1) { }

{ // block not attached to if
    cout << "\nWelcome to Slots";
}
else if (igame == 2) { } // this else has no matching if
{
    cout << "\nWelcome to Roulette";
}
else // this else has no matching if
{
    cout << "\nWelcome to Blackjack";
}
```